# Margin Distribution N-dimensional random vector

Tags: probability, bayesian, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, marginal-distribution

I have this exercise on my textbook and I can't understand how I have to do it.
I tried to compute the posterior but I don't understand if it's what the exercise requires.
Thanks

[image]

This is what I did which i don'tknow if it's correct:
$$\int_{R^n}\frac{exp(-\frac{1}{2}(x-S\theta)^T\frac{1}{\sigma^2}I_N(x-S\theta))}{\sqrt(det(2\pi\sigma^2I_n))}\frac{exp(-\frac{1}{2}(x-S\theta)^T\frac{1}{\tau^2}I_N(x-S\theta))}{\sqrt(det(2\pi\tau^2I_n))}$$
which will give me considering $$\sigma_1^2 = \sigma^2I_N $$ and $$\sigma_2^2 = \tau^2I_P$$ such that: $$p(y) = \frac{\sqrt(\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)}{2\pi\sigma_1\sigma_2} \exp(-\frac{(x-S\theta)^2}{2\sigma_1^2}-\frac{(x-\theta_0)^2}{2\sigma_2^2}+\frac{(\theta_0 - S\theta)^2}{2(\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)})$$

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: thank you, I've added my solution, but since it's just 2 row of exercise I didn't want to create any bias in the solution of the exercise